# Domain of a solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've  solved this Cauchy problem

$$y'= \frac{4\cos(x)^2-2}{\sin y}, \ \ \  \ \  y(0)=\frac\pi2.$$

I've found $y(x)=\arccos(-\sin(2x))$

The domain is $(0,\pi)$?

Answer (score 0):

**The function is defined everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$**

That's because even if $arccos(x)$ domain is only $[-1;\,1]$, $-sin(2x)$ is defined everywhere and return always a value in $[-1;\,1]$, so there's no point causing troubles to the $arccos(x)$ function.

***However***, the derivative as you reported it has not the same domain, because it's undefined wherever $sin(y) = 0$.

Then, solving $y(x) = \pm\frac{\pi}{2}$, you get that the derivative isn't defined in $\pi\left(n+\frac14\right)$ and $\pi\left(n+\frac34\right)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So the *actual* domain, in the context of the problem, is
$$\mathbb{R} - \left\{\pi\left(n+\frac14\right) \lor \pi\left(n+\frac34\right), \, \forall \, n \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$$

Comment: How can I prove that the graph of the solution is a segment?

Comment: Well, it isn't, it's a series of segments http://goo.gl/2iKqlP.
However check my answer edit.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of the solution of an ODE is an interval.

In particular, maximum domain of the solution of an IVP is the maximum interval in which the initial time (i.e., $x_0=0$) belongs.

In our case we are looking for an interval $I$, with $\pi/2\in I$, and the flux function
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{4\cos^2-2}{\sin y}
$$
is well defined, i.e., $\sin y(x)\ne 0$. This means, that $y(x)$ should avoid multiples of $\pi$. In particular, it should avoid $0$ and $\pi$.

But $y(x)=0$ (resp. $y(x)=\pi$), implies that $\,\arccos (-\sin 2x)=0$ (resp. $\pi$) 
or $-\sin (2x)=1$ (resp. $-1$), which holds (for the first time) if $x=-\pi/4$ (resp. $\pi/4$).

Thus maximum interval is $(-\pi/4,\pi/4)$.